# Design Room reservation availability check function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, e-commerce

I'm struggling on designing a good reservation system

In the scenario, each room has many room_skus,

each room_sku record represents a physical room

because we can have many real rooms belongs to the same room type.

However, I don't have any idea to implement the availability.

What I can think of is that add a new model RoomAvailablity.

If a user books a single room (room_number: 413) from 2016-04-11 to 2016-04-13

I will create three records on the table `RoomAvailablity`

- {room_sku_id: 413,  occupied_date: 2016-04-11}
- {room_sku_id: 413,  occupied_date: 2016-04-12}
- {room_sku_id: 413,  occupied_date: 2016-04-13}

Then, when another user tries to book  (room_number: 413) from 2016-04-12 to 2016-04-14

I will make a query like `count = RoomAvailablity.where(room_number:413, occupied_date >= 2016-04-12 and occupied_date <= 2016-04-14)`

If the `count > 0`, then the room is not available during the duration.

Is there any good recommendation to improve my thought?

## Room

```
HAS_MANY RoomSku

id: integer
name:string
type:string (Double, Single, Triple)
description:string
```

## RoomSku

```
belong_to: Room
HAS_MANY: RoomAvailablity
id: integer
name:string
```

## RoomAvailablity

```
belong_to: RoomSku
occupied_date: date
room_sku_id: integer
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, add a start date and end date to each availability.

```
belong_to: RoomSku
start_date: date
end_date: date
room_sku_id: integer
```

**Query**

```
RoomAvailablity.where(room_number: 413).where("start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?", end_date, start_date).count
```

Or you can use it alternatively.

**Find Available Rooms on date range**

```
RoomAvailability.where.not("start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?", end_date, start_date)
```

**If user has booked the room for only 1 day, use the same start and end date.**